# Checking equality of two TriMat matrices written to Matrix Market format in sprs does not work if insertion order is different

Tags: rust

I am trying to check if two Matrix Market format files contain the same matrix. In my actual code, due to the use of multi-threading, there is no guarantee that I am inserting items into a `TriMat` in the same order before being serialized to disk. As a result, when I load the resulting files and compare them, they are not always the same. How can I compare two different `.mtx` files and ensure that they are the same, regardless of insertion order?

Example code:

```
extern crate sprs;
use sprs::io::{write_matrix_market, read_matrix_market};
use sprs::TriMat;

fn main() {
    let mut mat = TriMat::new((4, 20));
    let mut vals = Vec::new();
    vals.push((0, 19, 1));
    vals.push((1, 14, 1));
    vals.push((1, 19, 1));
    vals.push((2, 17, 2));
    for (i, j, v) in vals {
        mat.add_triplet(i, j, v)
    }
    let _ = write_matrix_market("a.mtx", &mat).unwrap();

    let mut mat2 = TriMat::new((4, 20));
    let mut vals2 = Vec::new();
    vals2.push((0, 19, 1));
    vals2.push((1, 14, 1));
    vals2.push((2, 17, 2)); // different order
    vals2.push((1, 19, 1));
    for (i, j, v) in vals2 {
        mat2.add_triplet(i, j, v)
    }
    let _ = write_matrix_market("b.mtx", &mat2).unwrap();

    let seen_mat: TriMat<usize> = read_matrix_market("a.mtx").unwrap();
    let expected_mat: TriMat<usize> = read_matrix_market("b.mtx").unwrap();
    assert_eq!(seen_mat, expected_mat);
}
```

And the resulting error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `TriMatBase { rows: 4, cols: 20, row_inds: [0, 1, 1, 2], col_inds: [19, 14, 19, 17], data: [1, 1, 1, 2] }`,
 right: `TriMatBase { rows: 4, cols: 20, row_inds: [0, 1, 2, 1], col_inds: [19, 14, 17, 19], data: [1, 1, 2, 1] }`', src/main.rs:31:5
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.
```

You can see that these two matrices are actually identical, but that the items have been inserted in different orders.

Comment: Well, I not a mathematician but if you think there is a bug in this crate why don't you report this to... people who dev the crate ? supposedly on github ?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can convert to CSR to get it to work:

```
let seen_mat: TriMat<usize> = read_matrix_market("a.mtx").unwrap();
let expected_mat: TriMat<usize> = read_matrix_market("b.mtx").unwrap();
let a = seen_mat.to_csr();
let b = expected_mat.to_csr();
assert_eq!(a, b);
```